# I am getting some import error even though I pip installed it and The system cannot find the path specified error

Tags: python

Python shows something about path not specified and some import errors.

I tried importing all those packages required

even I have set the python path in environmental variables.

[image: the red circled path is the directory of my project.]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and do not use images of errors or code

Comment: If you have at least read the console log, you could have found the issue. Please do some research/work before you jump to stack overflow and ask a question.

Comment: i am trying to understand those thing, how it actually works. i am quite beginner. so still working with command prompt. may i know how to set the path from C to E?

Comment: Why use Command Prompt? Most programmers use VSCode or Pycharm or Jupyter for Python

Answer (score 0):

Error says nothing about imports or your python path or environment.

`C:\Users\fakabbir.amin\Desktop\pdfop` does not exist, which you can verify yourself without any code.

If you are expecting your code to read from the same folder as your "project", it is not. Without seeing any code, it's hard to say why

---

### Possible solution

Do not name your own file `cv2.py`. This conflicts with OpenCV module name, which you are trying to import

Comment: i am quite beginner, and I am trying to learn how code works internally. may i know how to set the right path from C to E??

Comment: You don't. You rename your `cv2.py` file to something else